# Updating ArcGIS Online with Safe FME without Edit Mode turned on

Tags: arcgis-online, fme-form, feature-service

I have an ArcGIS Online Group with approximately 60 Layers that need updated weekly from our Fiber Network. I have done some research on updating the ArcGIS Online Layers but the issue is having to change the settings to "Allow Edits."

This is causing a couple issues. The people using the maps should not be allowed to edit these particular layers, also it is causing confusion when I need to update and they see 60+ layers that can be edited. The second issue is the time it takes every week to update these layers when I have to go to each layer, turn on edit mode, update, then go back through and turn edit mode off on each of the layers. I am hoping there is away around this in some fashion.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using hosted feature layers in ArcGIS Online you can put these layers in a group that allows shared ownership and you open the layers with full editing mode. This will not require you to toggle editing on/off and for all other users of the maps with those layers will not notice any editing issues.

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/edit-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_3FE5B0299EB54506BEDEAFA3C22088A3

Comment: OK, I can see how this works. Within FME it looks as if I will have to add the suffix "&isAdmin=true" to the end of the feature service address. I am looking into a way to do this now.